# what's is the condition with arrays and vlookup?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm new using vba and I don't know how can I ask the following.

I have my database and it's looks like that:

```
Category    Description   Category1   Description1
 a            1              c          ____
 b            2              b          ____
 c            3              a          ____
 ...         ...            ...           ...
```

I have to copy the description in the description1 acording to the category.

Note: the category and description have the same lenght, but the category1 and description1 have another lenght.

I currently used the following code:

```
Private Sub clasi_Click()
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim final1, final2 As Integer
 Dim description As String
 Dim categoria As Single

 Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
 final1 = Application.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d:d")) '99 cells
 final2 = Application.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a:a"))  '656 cells

 For i = 1 To final2
   description = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 3).Value
   Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 8).Value =         
   Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(description, Range("a:b"), 2, 1)
 Next i

 End Sub
```

And appears: run-time error '1004' Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class.

I don't know what is the problem, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't the last parameter for VLOOKUP a TRUE/FALSE? Also, try `Set oRngUsed As Range : Set oRngUsed = Intersect(Range("a:b"),Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange) : WorksheetFunction.VLookup(description, oRngUsed, 2, FALSE)`

Comment: Is it Sheet1 or Sheet3 you want to store the VLookup result? Please double check and update the Post.

Comment: Okay, I try with your recomendations and it works better, but in the moment that the function don't find the cells with the condition, the code gets error. How can I fix it? (no all the category are in the category1)

Comment: Add `On Error Resume Next` above `For i`, then `On Error GoTo 0` below `Next i`. Almost write an Answer but your code got me confused which worksheet contains what...

Comment: Sorry, the sheet was the sheet1. I was wrong. However, it's works now :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

The next code works great!

```
 Private Sub clasificar_Click()
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim final1, final2 As Integer
 Dim description As String
  Dim categoria As Single

  Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
  final1 = Application.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d:d")) '99 cells
  final2 = Application.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a:a"))  '656 cells


  For i = 1 To final2
     On Error Resume Next
     description = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value =                
     Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(description, Range("a:b"), 2, 0)

     If Err.Number = 1004 Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value = "Sin 
     categoria"

  Next i
End Sub
```